# what does "argmax().I" mean in Julia

Tags: julia

Here is the great example from [StatWithJuliaBook](https://github.com/h-Klok/StatsWithJuliaBook) (please find the following)

It demos how to smooth a plot of stary sky [stars.png](https://github.com/h-Klok/StatsWithJuliaBook/blob/master/data/stars.png)

My question is about `argmax().I`. According to the author, "Note the use of the trailing “.I” at the end of each argmax, which extracts the values of the co-ordinates in column-major."

What does it mean? Is there other parameter? I can't find any description in the document.

According to author, it seems to be the position of column-wise maxmum value, yet when I tried `argmax(gImg, dims=2)`, the result is different.

```
#julia> yOriginal, xOriginal = argmax(gImg).I
#(192, 168)


#julia> yy, xx = argmax(gImg, dims = 2)
#400×1 Matrix{CartesianIndex{2}}:
# CartesianIndex(1, 187)
# CartesianIndex(2, 229)
 ⋮
# CartesianIndex(399, 207)
# CartesianIndex(400, 285)

#julia> yy, xx
#(CartesianIndex(1, 187), CartesianIndex(2, 229))
```

Please advise.

```
using Plots, Images; pyplot()

img = load("stars.png")
gImg = red.(img)*0.299 + green.(img)*0.587 + blue.(img)*0.114
rows, cols = size(img)

println("Highest intensity pixel: ", findmax(gImg))

function boxBlur(image,x,y,d)
    if x<=d || y<=d || x>=cols-d || y>=rows-d
        return image[x,y]
    else
        total = 0.0
        for xi = x-d:x+d
            for yi = y-d:y+d
                total += image[xi,yi]
            end
        end
        return total/((2d+1)^2)
    end
end

blurImg = [boxBlur(gImg,x,y,5) for x in 1:cols, y in 1:rows]

yOriginal, xOriginal = argmax(gImg).I
yBoxBlur, xBoxBlur   = argmax(blurImg).I

p1 = heatmap(gImg, c=:Greys, yflip=true)
p1 = scatter!((xOriginal, yOriginal), ms=60, ma=0, msw=4, msc=:red) 
p2 = heatmap(blurImg, c=:Greys, yflip=true)
p2 = scatter!((xBoxBlur, yBoxBlur), ms=60, ma=0, msw=4, msc=:red)

plot(p1, p2, size=(800, 400), ratio=:equal, xlims=(0,cols), ylims=(0,rows), 
    colorbar_entry=false, border=:none, legend=:none)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I` is a field in an object of type `CartesianIndex` which is returned by `argmax` when its argument has more than 1 dimension.

If in doubt always try using `dump`.

Please consider the code below:

```
julia> arr = rand(4,4)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.971271  0.0350186  0.20805   0.284678
 0.348161  0.19649    0.30343   0.291894
 0.385583  0.990593   0.216894  0.814146
 0.283823  0.750008   0.266643  0.473104

julia> el = argmax(arr)
CartesianIndex(3, 2)

julia> dump(el)
CartesianIndex{2}
  I: Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    1: Int64 3
    2: Int64 2
```

However, getting `CartesianIndex` object data via its internal structure is not very elegant. The nice Julian way to do it is to use the appropriate method:

```
julia> Tuple(el)
(3, 2)
```

Or just access the indices directly:

```
julia> el[1], el[2]
(3, 2)
```

Comment: I was not quite familiar with the tuple type. According to definition, it is an “ordered & immutable” sequence. To me, the tuple is an ordered version of the original sequence. Not only that, it also gives the position marker, say, which one is the maximum in argmax(). Great! I think I hv better picture, and thanks for the ‘dump’ tip, many thanks.